# What is a Beilinson spectral sequence?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, homological-algebra, spectral-sequences

I'm writing to ask just a question. I would like to understand better what is the Beilinson's spectral sequence and how it can be used. Is there any useful and clear reference you advice to someone who just knows what is a spectral sequence? Any answer will be appreciated.

Comment: http://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/978-1-4757-1460-9.pdf

Comment: or http://mathoverflow.net/questions/77071/generalized-beilinson-spectral-sequences

Comment: The general case is nicely stated in Christian Boening's paper http://www.mathematik.uni-bielefeld.de/documenta/vol-11/11.pdf